Handle or disable WCS (GeoServer) trimmed-down coverage response when asking data on the bounds of the raster
I process a large raster as smaller 1700x1700 square tiles (including 100+100 pixel overlap on all sides).
The source is a raster pyramid on GeoServer (2.20.3 or 2.23.1 idem).
I had no issue when using WMS, everything worked perfectly.
I switched to WCS to get raw and 4+band data.
When my tile request hits the outer bounds of the raster in WCS however, geoserver sometimes returns a smaller raster and a smaller coverage than the one I asked for.
I can understand why it might clip the request to its actual raster data.
a) I found no way to tell GeoServer to "extend" the geo bounds of the layer with NODATA eg., which would be the simplest solution to my problem by far
b) I found no reliable way to cast the returned data back in my tile system, to the point I almost start to think there is a bug in GeoServer:
I ask for GeoTIFF and I use Java mil.nga.tiff package, so I can parse the FieldTagType "ModelTransformation" of the returned raster.
I guess this field to rely upon is ModelTransformation, Tag=34264 with values, eg. as [0.12, 0, 0, 423057.48, 0, -0.12, 0, 2975082.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0]
There is no clear information about the fields, but I easily guess field #0 is the pixel size as eastings, #3 is the tile easting "origin", #5 is the pixel size in northings and #7 the is the tile origin in "northings" (I have no clue about the others, which all seem constant)
As shown (-0.12 ipo 0.12), northings are inverted, which I guess reflects the usual annoying problem between raster & geography.
Now the weird thing: I have no issue processing eastings, but I really fail at fixing the northings.
I tried various ways to project, including casting one way or another (project received tile into expected tile, or lookup pixels of target tile into source tile). Now way for Y.
On some tiles, the returned data seems misaligned and the projected content is not at the proper place: see how the N-E tile is both trimmed north and south as if there was an approximation or a rounding error on the returned coverage.

Do you have clues or hints to get me right ?
Is this trimming/cropping a common problem ?
Should I build the WCS request another way ? Tiles urls are like https://geo.mygeoserver.com/geoserver/wms/wcs?service=WCS&request=GetCoverage&version=2.0.1&coverageId=ws%3Alayername&format=image%2Ftiff&rangesubset=R&subsettingCrs=EPSG%3A32637&subset=E(423045.48,423249.48)&subset=N(2974518.48,2974722.48))
Sorry for this long question.

The meaning of the Tag=34264 is defined in the GeoTIFF standard https://docs.ogc.org/is/19-008r4/19-008r4.html. The 6 most commonly used parameters are explained in a more understandable way in this ESRI worldfile article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file. It looks like you have guessed them right.
When it comes to filling the requested "extra" area with nodata, I agreee that it would be convenient. Unfortunately it is against the WCS 2.0.1 standard https://portal.ogc.org/files/09-110r4.

The WCS Core standard defines the domain subsetting operation which
delivers all data from a coverage inside a specified request envelope
(“bounding box”), relative to the coverage’s envelope – more
precisely, the intersection of the request envelope with the coverage
envelope.

This part of the standard seems to say that cutting the response to match with the extent of the whole coverage is correct. However, some other parts of the standard seem to say that the server should send just on exception.

Requirement 32 /req/core/getCoverage-request-trim-within-extent:
Let the extent of the coverage’s gml:Envelope along the dimension
specified in the trim request range from L to H. Then, for the trim
bounds trimLow and trimHigh the following shall hold:
L <= trimLow <= trimHigh <= H

And later about the error codes:

InvalidSubsetting 404
Operation request contains an invalid subsetting value; either a
trim or slice parameter value is outside the extent of the coverage or, in > a trim operation, a lower bound is above the upper bound

I do not understand the weird thing with the northings. If the returned data does not match with the requested N(2974518.48,2974722.48) it does feel like a bug in GeoServer.

Many thanks for the links and clarification, I failed to read that in the geoserver own doc, and struggled with the proper ones. Meanwhile, I was able to download the partial tiles from geoserver from within my code, save them as geotiff and open them with QGIS. They are all well placed so all the blame definitely ends up on me.
I probably would better use gdal lib in java to re-place the tile portion into its expected square footprint, and stop trying to do it on my own.

Or you could use the GeoTools geoTiff code in java
